# Lazy loading hasMany collections in ember-data using links

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am in a position where passing an array of ids back from the server is not possible or practical.

I am using the 'links' attribute instead in the JSON response which works well.

```
{ 
   "blog":{
      "id":1,
      "active":true,
      "name":"Testing",
      "category":2,
      "links" : {
         "posts" : "posts"
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that often I will not need to display the posts and therefore requesting the data is just a waste.  I have found that using links automatically fetches the posts even if I have never accessed the collection.

What I want is for ember-data to only request the posts hasMany array if the posts is accessed.

```
blog.get('post') //only now will the server request be made to get related posts.
```

Is there a way I can lazy load using links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your model code? Did you define  the posts async? This should work:

```
posts: DS.hasMany('post', { async: true })
```

Comment: you are correct, turns out it does in fact work.  I think I was experiencing this behaviour before I put `{async : true}` in my code and thought it was still occurring.